# INTLTOOL_EXTRACT breaks translatable lines

Tags: gettext, autotools

I don't know why but my source code line and the one in the pot file are not the same, source code:

```
#include <libintl.h>

#define _(String) gettext(String)

/* more code */

printf (_("Error while saving file in %s:\n\n%s"), ...);
```

Now, in the pot file, looks like this:

```
#: ../src/main.c:72
#, c-format
msgid ""
"Error while saving file in %s:\n"
"\n"
"%s"
msgstr ""
```

Question: Why is the break line and how to avoid it? The expected is:

```
#: ../src/main.c:72
#, c-format
msgid "Error while saving file in %s:\n\n%s"
msgstr ""
```

PS: I'm using autotools, so everything is generated with gettextize and intltoolize.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The two forms are equivalent. Different pot file writers format their pot files differently, and this is just the way that gettext/intltool does it.

I don't know how to avoid the line breaks, but I wouldn't waste time trying.